# MSIEmbeddedChainer & MSIEmbeddedUI

Tags: c#, wpf, wix, wix3, wix3.5

i am finding some example source codes for the MSIEmbeddedChainer & MSIEmbeddedUI. wix v3.0 has <EmbeddedChainer> command, but there's no info of how to use (or probably incomplete implementation). i want to chain my msis. however, there are very little details to this topic. msi 4.5 has very nice features with MSIEmbeddedChainer & MSIEmbeddedUI. unfortunately, wix v3.0 doesn't seem to support at the moment. i see the wix announced that wix burn project started along with wix v3.6. but i think there are long way to go for this implementation.

there are some developers wrote their own codes for this MSI chains with wpf and c#/c++. i just want to have a sneak, so i have an idea how to code them too. again unfortunately, i don't see any...

can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Burn.exe in Wix 3.6 onwards provides this feature by using [`Chain`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_chain.htm) element and [`MsiPackage`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_msipackage.htm). Have a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

an MSI chainer is nothing more than a program that you write yourself that calls your MSI's in the proper order with the proper attributes and properties.  The MSIEmbeddedChainer element is actually included in WiX 3.0 (I am actually using it in my current istallation.  Sadly I am not the one writing the chainer, I am only doing the MSI's.  Try checking the [WiX page](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) for the element EmbeddedChainer (without the MSI) and you should see all the available elements.